# imagecopymerge not responding

Tags: php, image, copying

I am trying to merge two images with image copy merge.  This is the code I have:

```
<?php

$unframedPhoto = ('unframedPhoto.jpg');
$frame = ('frame.jpg');

imagecopymerge($frame, $unframedPhoto, 200, 200, 0, 0, 800, 800,0);

header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($frame, 'framedImage.jpg');

?>
```

That's the only code in my script.  I am executing it by going to the .php file on my localhost, and I am getting no response.  I do not see a new image 'framedImage.jpg' in my directory.

Any ideas what's going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do like this...

```
<?php

$unframedPhoto= imagecreatefromjpeg('unframedPhoto.jpg');
$frame  = imagecreatefromjpeg('frame.jpg');
imagecopymerge($frame, $unframedPhoto, 200, 200, 0, 0, 800, 800,0);
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
imagejpeg($frame);
imagedestroy($frame);
imagedestroy($frame);
```

Comment: This seems to be working now, although there is a delay in the image appearing my directory..